# Can't run 3440x1440 monitor and 1920x1080 monitor at the same time

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

Relevant hardware:

- [Acer Predator XR341CK 75Hz 34.0"](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model/UM.CX1AA.001) Monitor
- Samsung 49UB8500 TV
- [MSI GeForce GTX 780 3GB TWIN FROZR](http://www.msi.com/product/vga/N780-TF-3GD5OC.html) Video Card
- [Asus Maximus VI Extreme ATX LGA1150](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/MAXIMUS_VI_EXTREME/) Motherboard
- Corsair 1200W 80+ Platinum Certified Fully-Modular ATX Power Supply
- Intel 4770K Processor

I have a TV connected as a secondary monitor via HDMI and I *had* a standard 1080p monitor connected (via DVI) as my primary for years. The TV is capable of 4k but I run it at 1080p.

I just got the [Acer XR341CK](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model/UM.CX1AA.001) (it runs at 3440x1440, 75Hz). I hooked the Acer into my display port at the same time as my TV (both hooked into my video card) but the Acer won't turn on. When I disconnect the TV from the HDMI, the Acer works fine. While they are both connected the TV will go blank for a second every 10 seconds or so. It appears to be trying to get the Acer connected but it fails. When I check the display settings, the TV appears as display #2 but the Acer doesn't show up at all.

Tried plugging and unplugging the monitors in every combination. Restarting. Updating video drivers. I don't think it's a power issue, I've got a 1200w supply.

*Something to note:* when I first got the Acer they worked together. One change I did make was I changed the Acer to be my primary monitor. Problems seems to have started shortly after. Trouble is, I can't try switching it back because there needs to be two monitors actively connected before you can choose the primary monitor (I don't have the old one anymore). Also, having my TV set to the primary display isn't ideal since it's only for entertainment.

Comment: the first link is the graphics card and not the monitor.

Comment: And what about your onboard processor. How old is it?

Comment: It's an intel 4770K